# jax-rs : parse the ArrayList from Java using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jax-rs

I have an ArrayList returned from my CXF Rest service, but I am unable to parse it to display the details on the client side using JQuery.

Appreciate any help

thanks,
Bob

```
 **Sample Code:**
    This is how my code looks :
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getDetails(@PathParam("id") Long id) {

    // data is retreied from database.

    List<UserBO> userBOList = new ArrayList<UserBO>();
    Response response = Response
    .status(Response.Status.OK)
    .entity(userBOList)
    .build();
    return response;
    }

    ===================================================================
    My Javascript code:

    var url  = "http://localhost:8080/user/1";

    $("#submit").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: url,
       beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
          xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Origin","null");
       },
       contentType : "application/json",
       dataType : "json",

       success: function(data) {
            alert( "Data Saved :  " + data );
       }

     });

    });
```

Comment: can u add sample ArrayList returned by REST API

Comment: I was able to get the list and print the list in javascript as follows:

In the java code , while constructing the Response Object, I did the following :

    Response response = Response
    .ok()
    .entity(JSON.toString(userBOList))
    .build();
and In the Javascript to print the list :

    success: function(data) {
      alert( "Data retreived :  " + data );
    }

Comment: can you add some part of json, or you can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through an array in JavaScript like this:

```
for (a in Array){
    var item = Array[a];
}
```